# Remove conflicting dependencies when reinstalling with IzPack

Tags: jar, dependencies, conflict, izpack

I have a grails application and an installer for it. Everything is working with no problem. But, I recently updated the version of the HttpClient. The problem happens when a customer installs the new version of the application (without uninstalling the older version). The IzPack just copies all the files, replacing the ones with the same name. So, it creates conflicts with the older version of HttpClient (4.0.1) and the newer version (4.2). To be more specific, there are httpclient-xxx-4.2.jar files and httpclient-xxx-4.2.jar files. The application stops working because of this conflict.

I'd like to know if there's any way to remove the jar files of the lib directory BEFORE the IzPack copies the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this article about running a script file after the installation: http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/06/14/installation-with-izpack-launching-bat-files/

So, I configured the IzPack to extract the jar files in a templib directory and created a script to delete the jar files of lib and move the new jars from templib to lib.